# PHP cross-domain sessions

Tags: php, session

I seem to be having a problem with cross-domain sessions.
I have set the session name on both (sub) domains and it is still not working.
When I set the session I also output $_SESSION and username is set on sub1.x.com but when I try to access it on sub2.x.com it does not output. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's what I am doing:

`session_name('gbixtld');
 ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.gbizit.uk');
 ini_set('session.save_path', '/var/lib/php/session');
 session_start();`

Comment: check `session_id()`. if you get different values, then your session cookie is set incorrectly and isn't crossing the domains.

Comment: Both subdomains output gbixtld.

Comment: try to use [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) and [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) instead of `ini_set`, also - is it the same physical host behind both domains?

Comment: that's the session name. that's irrelevant. you need to check the session ID, which is a random alphanumeric string.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. Session ID's are different. I have previously tried session_set_cookie_params and that also produced the same outcome.